# Astro project on Vercel deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vercel, astrojs

Title:
Error when deploying Astro project on Vercel: "500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR - Code: FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED"

Issue Description:
When attempting to deploy my Astro project on Vercel, the deployment process completes successfully, but I encounter the following error:

500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
Code: FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED
This issue is accompanied by the following log information:

Time: October 06 12:22:41.74 GMT+02:00
Request Path: /
Status Code: 500
Host: 7sb8p-1696587762095-ea66c95e5111
Request User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Level: Error
Environment: preview
Branch: v04
Cache: MISS
Type: Serverless Function
Function: /render
Runtime: Node.js 18.x
Execution Duration / Limit: 241ms / 10s
Memory Used / Limit: 19 MB / 1024 MB
In addition, the following module not found error is reported in the logs:

plaintext
Copy code
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/var/task/dist/entry.mjs' imported from /var/task/___vc/__launcher/__launcher.js
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:329:11)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:992:10)
...

I have also tried creating a new project with the same src folder, but the issue persists during deployment on Vercel. Previous versions of the project worked without any problems.

Can someone please help me identify and resolve the "FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED" error and the module not found issue during the deployment of my Astro project on Vercel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem as you. I resolved deleting the .vercel folder when I checked the build in local. I deleted that folder and then put the folder on the .gitignore file.

After that, Vercel rebuild the project and it works.

I hope it helps you.